# Mostrar fecha y hora en un campo SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, base-de-datos

He hecho una vista de una tabla y en esa tabla de la cual hago la vista, el campo fecha aparece así:

- ejem. 2021-12-30 00:00:00 y es de tipo **date**

Luego otro campo que es hora que es de tipo **time**:

- ejem. 1754-01-01 12:03:59.

El problema que me encuentro es, que al definir el campo *fecha* en la `vista` me debería aparecer con la fecha y la hora correctas:

- ejem. 2021-12-30 12:03:59

Pero no sé cómo unirlas.

Ya vi una posible solución en este foro, pero no me vale porque me dice:

> Error de desbordamiento aritmético al convertir expression al tipo de
> datos datetime

Comment: Puedes colgar el codigo por el que te da error? asi te podremos ayudar.

Comment: Además del código que te da error, es importante tener la definición de las tablas con las columnas que utilizas, y un ejemplo de datos, ya que ese *time*, no entra en el intervalo de valores que define un tipo de dato `Time` de `SQL Server`. [time](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/sql/t-sql/data-types/time-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15)

Comment: @Caldodeparticulasprimigenio yo he puesto CONVERT(DATETIME, TABLA.[Fecha]) + CONVERT(DATETIME, TABLA.[Hora]) esta es la solucion que me he encontrado aqui, pero me aparece ese error de desbordamiento aritmético. Ya se que los campos que quiero unir son de tipo date y otro time supongo que por eso da error pero no tengo ni idea de como debería ser.Gracias por tu respuesta.

Comment: @Javifer2 el tipo de datos definido en el campo de la vista es datetime, entiendo que estoy haciendo un cambio de tipo de dato y pensaba que con el convert valdría. Como juntando un date y un time en un datetime. Entiendo que ese pueda ser el problema.Gracias por tu respuesta.

Answer (score 1):

Una de las soluciones es juntar un date como varchar, luego un espacio y un time como varchar

```
Declare @column date = '20210101'
Declare @column2 time(0) = '08:00'

Select
    Cast((
      cast(@column as varchar(10)) 
    + ' '
    + Cast(@column2 as varchar(10))
    ) as datetime)
```

[image: Result]

También es igual de valido, castear directamente el date como datetime y sumarle el time. Siempre y cuando la versión sea superior a 2012 (esto habría que confirmarlo)

```
Declare @column date = '20210101'
Declare @column2 time(0) = '08:00'

Select cast(@column as datetime) + cast(@column2 as datetime)
```

[image: res2]

Comment: me sigue apareciendo el mismo error, es que lo que quiero hacer es un campo definiendolo en una nueva tabla sin necesidad de usar funciones o por ejemplo un select, es solo definir el campo.

Comment: Haber..... lo que quieres hacer, y lo que se pueda hacer, siempre pueden ser cosas diferentes. Edita la pregunta. Pon la definición de la tabla. Luego carga en un script los datos que tienes, y el resultado que esperas y obtendrás una respuesta que no te de error. Además escribe lo que te resuelve Select @@version para saber cual es el motor.